# Как проигрывать WAV аудио из Resources c MediaPleyr? (Winform)

Tags: c#, winforms

Я пытаюсь воспроизвести звуковой файл в моем приложении через класс MediaPlayer из Resources, но выдает ошибку 
[image: Ошибка]

`private void button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var p1 = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
            p1.Open(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/_1.wav"));
            p1.Play();
        }`

Что не так с моим путем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что MediaPlayer не поддерживает [Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx). Поэтому необходимо держать медиа файлы в распакованном виде (хотя бы рядом с exe файлом), и открывать их используя относительный URI.

Для удобства управления медиа файлами и развертывания приложения, файлы можно добавить в проект и установить их свойство "Copy to Output Directory" в "Copy Always" или "Copy if Newer". Подробнее - в принятом ответе на этот вопрос: [VS2010 How to include files in project, to copy them to build output directory automatically during build or publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596508/vs2010-how-to-include-files-in-project-to-copy-them-to-build-output-directory-a).

Если по какой-то причине медиа файлы необходимо упаковывать в exe файл, тогда из необходимо извлекать и сохранять во временные файлы перед проигрыванием.

Чтобы извлечь файл из ресурсов приложения, можно воспользоваться методом [Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream(v=vs.110).aspx). В параметр метода передается путь, началом которого служит  [Default Namespace](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSNamespaces.aspx), а затем идет путь до файла в самом проекте. Вместо слеша используется точка.

```
Assembly executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Stream resourceStream = executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ApplicationDefaultNamespace.Resources._1.wav");
Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite("_1.wav");
resourceStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
fileStream.Flush();
fileStream.Close();
Uri relativeUri = new Uri("_1.wav");
p1.Open(relativeUri);
```

Для написания ответа использовались следующие материалы:

[Media element and uri resource](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c152ebf0-7593-4bfd-84bc-22bfd9c38076/media-element-and-uri-resource?forum=wpf)

[WPF|Использование ресурсов|Упакованные URI](http://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/UI_WPF/level7/7_9.php)

[Save and load MemoryStream to/from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624071/save-and-load-memorystream-to-from-a-file)